# Структура общения клиент-сервера через ObjectOutput(Input)Stream Java

Tags: java, клиент-сервер

Помогите понять как правильно настроить структура общения через объекты.
Сервер:

```
ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(7800);
Socket socket = null;
Data data;
while (serversocket != null) {
        socket = serversocket.accept();
        obIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        while ((data = (Data) obIn.readObject()) != null){
              System.out.println(data.x); //1ый результат - 100, 2ой - 100
        }
}
```

Клиент:

```
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 7800);
        Data data = new Data();
        data.x=100;
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(data);
        out.flush();
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        data.x=200;
        out.writeObject(data);
        out.flush();
```

Такой вариант не подходит так как out записывает кэш и значение в объекте меняться не будет. Я прочитал, что есть 2 варианта:

1. После out.flush(); написать - out.reset();, который очищает весь кэш объекта, но мне такой вариант не подходит, долго объяснять почему.
2. Закрывать поток out.close() и запускать новый. Но я когда его закрываю, закрывается и сам сокет и приходится заново подключать клиента (проверять логин, пароль и тд). Посоветуйте, как должен правильно работать такой клиент сервер?

Comment: там еще есть [`writeUnshared`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: я так понимаю, вам нужны потоки. посмотрите мой ответ в [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624944/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-tcp/624945#624945) статье